# python, regex, matching strings with repeating characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search Apache log files for specific entries related to specific vulnerability scans.  I need to match strings from a separate file against the URI content in the weblogs.  Some of the strings I am trying to find contain repeating special characters like '?'.

For example, I need to be able to match an attack that contains just the string '????????' but I don't want to be alerted on the string '??????????????????' because each attack is tied to a specific attack ID number.  Therefore, using:

```
if attack_string in log_file_line:
    alert_me()
```

...will not work.  Because of this, I decided to put the string into a regex:

```
if re.findall(r'\%s' % re.escape(attack_string),log_file_line):
    alert_me()
```

...which did not work either because any log file line containing the string '????????' is matched even if there are more than 8 '?' in the log file line.

I then tried adding boundaries to the regex:

```
if re.findall(r'\\B\%s\\B' % re.escape(attack_string),log_file_line):
    alert_me()
```

...which stopped matching in both cases.  I need to be able to dynamically assign the string I am looking for but I don't want to match on just any line that contains the string.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is there whitespace after the attack string?

Comment: If you use raw string, you shouldn't double up the \. Check whether this is the problem.

Comment: `r'\?\?\?\?\?\?\?\?(?!\?)'` Not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: If there is whitespace after the successfully found string, this regex would cut it  re.findall(r'\%s\s' % re.escape(attack_string),log_file_line)

Comment: @Mozoby and Tadgh - There isn't always going to be a whitespace character after the string.  Also, sometimes there may be more than one string that needs to match on a particular log file line before alerting. Each signature contains one or more string(s) that must be matched in order. On each iteration, a new string from the signature stack is placed in attack_string and compared to log_file_line.  Since "GET /vulnerable.page????????" and "GET /vulnerable.page/????????/gotya.exploit" and "GET /vulnerable.page" are all different signatures, I can't necessarily count on whitespaces.

Comment: @JoelCornett - The string '????????' is just the example that came to mind because it is all special characters. The list of signatures contains many different values that are placed into attack_string. Some example values include: 'modules.php?' or '?/ ' or '/WebID/IISWebAgentIF.dll' or '../' or '|3d 7c|' So, I need to be able to properly define boundaries in: `if re.findall(r'\%s' % re.escape(attack_string),log_file_line):`

Comment: Can you give an example of the string that should match and the string that shouldn't. How do you manualy recognize that attack_string isn't a part of something else?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(?:[^?]|^)\?{8}(?:[^?]|$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?-imsx:(?:[^?]|^)\?{8}(?:[^?]|$))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^?]                     any character except: '?'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \?{8}                    '?' (8 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^?]                     any character except: '?'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```